# How to Post Laravel Token Hash in Blueimp Jquery File Upload

Tags: laravel, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and Blueimp Jquery File Upload. I'm using my own uploadHandler.

And i have a problem with deleting files: "Token Mismatch Error"

How can i post csrf_token() result while deleting file ?

Comment: Post the delete code

Comment: Check out Laravel docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using jquery try this:

1. Add this meta tag to your blade

   ```
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   ```
2. Add this in JavaScript

   ```
               // set up jQuery with the CSRF token, or else post routes will fail

       $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });
   ```

Comment: Good answer. This is the [recommended approach](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection) in the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

First go to app/Http/kernel.php file
and add comment this line

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

into

```
// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

Try this....

Comment: This **removes** the protection. Better to send the token with the request and keep the protection.

Comment: I am tempted to upvote this answer, because it's funny. :D